# Get webrick server to run on port 80 with postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I'm getting a postgres error when I try to run webrick on port 80 like so:

`rvmsudo rails s -p 80`

I then get this error:

```
Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@app/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize': FATAL:  role "root" does not exist (PG::Error)
```

Plus much more to the stack trace.

I tried changing my user to `root` in database.yml, but no luck.  Any suggestions?

EDIT:  Trying to run locally, not for production.

Comment: Don't use webrick as a production webserver. And NEVER EVER run your webserver as root.

Comment: It's quite common to run a more powerful HTTP server like Apache, ngnix, etc on port 80 and have it act as a reverse proxy for application servers. This configuration is well documented and fairly simple. It means your appserver doesn't have to run as a privileged user.

Answer (score 0):

First, I agree not to run production web servers as root.  That's just a bad idea.

As for what is going on here, you are not supplying PostgreSQL login credentials and so it is sending the process owner's name, and no password.  You are also obviously using an authentication method that does not require passwords on the PostgreSQL side.  I would suggest connecting over tcp/ip (specifying localhost as the host), and making sure that the auth type in the `pg_hba.conf` is set to `md5` (but if you can't do this cert auth may be ok with a client cert).

From there make sure that the username and password are properly specified.